# Android Room database - how to get context in Automigration?

Tags: android, android-room, auto-migration

I need to change the **Room database** schema. In addition to the usual things like deleting a database table or renaming columns, I need to do some data transformations.

I have created an **Automigration** class and I want to do the data transformations in the **onPostMigrate** method.

But for data transformations I need to read some data from assets and I need **context**. Is there any way to pass this context to the Automigration class in the constructor?

Something like this

```
public class MyAutoMigration implements AutoMigrationSpec {

    private Context context;

    public MyAutoMigration(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostMigrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Perform data transformations here
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances of `AutoMigrationSpec` are created automatically and you can't inject any parameters into them.

If you need a reference to a `Context` during the migration, then you can do a [manual migration](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#manual).

Here's an example:

```
public class Migration1to2 extends Migration {
    private final Context context;

    public Migration1to2(Context context) {
        super(1, 2);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // todo: implement the migration logic.
        // database.execSQL(...)
    }
}
```

Note that numbers 1 and 2 are the starting and ending versions of the database.

Now you can create your migration and add it to the database:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MyDb.class, "database-name")
        .addMigrations(Migration1to2(getApplicationContext()))
        .build();
```

Comment: That conforms also to what the OP is saying. He wants to apply some specific logic for the data transformation, that is he has some specifics on migrating the database. It makes sense that he has to define his own migration rather than doing that on the onPostMigrate() of an automatic migration.

Comment: I thought of this solution too. It means I have to do the schema change myself. Changing a column name in a database is not trivial, and things like modifying indexes are not easy. Especially if I want to make sure I do it exactly the same way as room when creating a completely new database for another user.